# Trying to click on element

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I'm trying to learn to write userscripts and thought a good simple starting point would be a simple activity liker for [anilist](http://anilist.co) but i have been unable to actually like the activities...

my userscrypt:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    function like(){
        const divs = document.getElementsByClassName("like-wrap activity");

        for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
            let button = divs[i].childNodes[2]
            if(!button.classList.contains("liked")){
                button.click()
            }
        }
    }

    var button = document.createElement("Button");
    button.innerHTML = "like";
    button.style = "bottom:10px;right:10px;position:fixed;z-index:9999999"
    button.onclick = like;
    document.body.appendChild(button);
})();
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm assuming it's something really obvious I'm missing because I'm new at this...

Comment: what page on that site has a like button?

Comment: @Samathingamajig This on for example https://anilist.co/user/Methuselah/ (random user that showed up on global). My intention is to like all unliked activities.

Comment: Replace `let button = divs[i].childNodes[2]`  with `let button = divs[i].children[2]`.

Comment: @connexo with that I get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')"

Answer (score 0):

If you change you selector to this:

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll(".like-wrap.activity .button:not(.liked):nth-child(2)")
```

then you can just iterate through all and click on them:

```js
for (const div of divs) {
  div.click();
}
```

Comment: This is a simplified version of what i had. But it doesn't work... Nothing happens. So I'm starting to wonder if maybe the event is not on this div... Or something. How would i go about finding that out?

Comment: @Nulk I believe this site has something where `div.click()` doesn't work, but someone actually clicking works (maybe detecting position of the mouse?), so this might be impossible

Comment: Do you know if or how i can get around it?